# How can I get city name from coordinates [unlimited requests]?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to get the city name from a user's GeoLocation. I am aware of Google's Reverse Geocoding service, but it has a limit of 2500 requests per day.

Is there a service which does unlimited amount of requests or is there any alternate efficient way to map coordinates to city ?

Comment: This is not a question about coding

Comment: There are some services like geonames.org, but I think you must pay something for unlimited requests in all of them

Comment: @darkermuffin if and when you try out a solution to this do feel free to update in the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OpenStreetMap ([OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API)) API based tools to do reverse geocoding. It is an open data project and so there is [no pricing](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/3440/cost-of-commercial-use) (though you could help them out with a donation). They do have some restrictions on the [usage and bandwidth](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy)

One such tool is [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding) using which you can get the city address using latitude and longitude co-ordinates. Here is an example from the linked wiki

> https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

Gives you this result

```
<reversegeocode timestamp="Sat, 20 Jan 18 10:53:40 +0000" attribution="Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" querystring="format=xml&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1">
<result place_id="91015268" osm_type="way" osm_id="90394420" lat="52.54877605" lon="-1.81627033283164" boundingbox="52.5487321,52.5488299,-1.8163514,-1.8161885">

137, Pilkington Avenue, Sutton Coldfield, Birmingham, West Midlands Combined Authority, West Midlands, England, B72 1LH, United Kingdom
</result>
<addressparts>
<house_number>137</house_number>
<road>Pilkington Avenue</road>
<suburb>Sutton Coldfield</suburb>
<city>Birmingham</city>
<county>West Midlands Combined Authority</county>
<state_district>West Midlands</state_district>
<state>England</state>
<postcode>B72 1LH</postcode>
<country>United Kingdom</country>
<country_code>gb</country_code>
</addressparts>
</reversegeocode>
```

**UPDATE**

1. Please refer to the [usage guidelines](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) of the Nominatim service before using it
2. You could also take a look at these other [search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) for OSM